# Send mail when Laravel Dusk Test Failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

How can I execute a function or send a mail with a screenshot when specific laravel dusk test failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `TestCase::captureFailuresFor()` in `DuskTestCase`:

```php
protected function captureFailuresFor($browsers) {
    parent::captureFailuresFor($browsers);

    // TODO
}
```